# C++ Armadillo: Irregular element access

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm looking at Armadillo from a Matlab background and am curious if there's a way to efficiently access irregular elements in a matrix/vector. I'm aware that I can access a continuous part of a matrix with something like

```
A.submat(span(p,r), span(q,s))
```

but I'm used to being able to pull out the odd rows and even columns of a matrix like so in Matlab:

```
a([1 3 5], [2 4])
```

Is there an equivalent way to access arbitrarily spaced elements of a matrix with Armadillo?

Comment: see the section on non-contiguous submatrices in the documentation for armadillo: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat  try this form: X.submat(vector_of_row_indices, vector_of_column_indices)

Comment: Thanks. The included PDF documentation doesn't mention that.

Comment: The PDF states that it was written for Armadillo version 2.4 (see the front page). Armadillo is now at version 4.650